# Determining weights and normalization for orthogonality given all polynomials

Tags: special-functions, orthogonality, hypergeometric-function, orthogonal-polynomials

If, from certain arguments, I am aware that polynomials of order n, $P_n(t)$, are orthogonal with respect to some weight and some normalization, what is the best or most general way to find out the weight and normalization?
Specific details:
The specific problem I am having concerns $P_n(t)=F_n(t)+G_{n-1}(t)+t H_{n-2}(t)$ where $F,G,H$ are known orthogonal polynomials but with different weights.

Comment: Until I've seen your "certain arguments" that those combinations of orthogonal polynomials are orthogonal, they're uncertain arguments for me, sorry! In a very specific setting, it's possible that those polynomials still satisfy a three-term recurrence, and then, they are orthogonal, but it's quite difficult to recover the weight from that (normalization would be easier).

Comment: @vector: how is it possible to find the normalisation without referring to the weight with respect to which these polynomials are orthogonal?

Comment: Show me your three-term recurrence, and I'll show you the normalization. How can **you** say they're orthogonal if you don't know the weight?